# How to Update Look and Feel of Older Windows User Interface?

Tags: delphi, user-interface, delphi-5, delphi-xe6

I have a really solid computer program that was written for Windows XP. The program still works great and I would like to update the look and feel of the user interface.

At this time, I would like to give the buttons etc. a more sleek, contemporary look.  Much better would be to allow functionality of touch and swipe etc. for tablets and such.

Can anyone tell me what tools in Delphi are used to accomplish this? For instance, do I need to change every button and object manually through object inspector or can I update/modify all objects objects within a project using a single set of commands?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can start by enabling Windows themes, using Project->Options->Appearance from the IDE's main menu. It's on by default since D2007, but won't be on because your app is coming from Delphi 5. (New projects have it turned on by default, but the IDE can't know if you want it enabled or not when importing older projects.)

You can then start looking at adding gesture support by looking into the documentation for `TGestureManager` and `TGesture`. There's a `TGestureManager` for both VCL and FireMonkey (FMX) applications.

Note that for cross-platform support (Android, iOS, and OS X) you'll need to port your application from the VCL to FMX.

Comment: Awesome Ken, I will certainly do this.  Thank you.

Comment: @KenWhite: None of the things you mention exist in Delphi 5. For theme support, at least, you can use [SoftGems XP Theme Manager](http://soft-gems.net/index.php/controls/windows-xp-theme-manager) (which was integrated into a later VCL release), but gesturing support has to be implemented manually unless you can find a third-party library to handle it. And forget about cross-platform development, unless you port the Delphi 5 app to FreePascal.

Comment: @Remy: The poster is asking about updating old Delphi 5 projects to XE6 (see the tags). Therefore, everything I mention is available in XE6, and is relevant to opening existing D5 projects in XE6 (including the need to port existing VCL code to FMX). :-) Mike's Theme Manager is not relevant to XE6, as the VCL has built-in theme support since D2007.

Comment: @KenWhite: The tags may have multiple Delphi versions mentioned, but the poster did not say anything about porting a Delphi 5 app to XE6, that is an assumption you are making. All he said was that he wanted to update his UI, but not in which version.  Everything you say applies to XE6 only (the built-in theme support is based on the original Theme Manager). And as I am sure you are aware, suggesting that a Delphi 5 project should be opened in the XE6 IDE is not a good idea since automated project upgrades rarely work correctly.

Comment: @Remy: If the poster has XE6, all of the information I provided is relevant. If the poster had asked about updating a D5 app only, it wouldn't be. Your assumption is that the poster didn't ask about porting, but as they accepted my answer it would appear that my understanding was correct. :-) The question also asks about "tools available in Delphi", and the answer to that would be "none" for D5 as themed drawing didn't exist, but the "Enable themes" is available in XE6 (and thus in Delphi).